# What does KVL imply about about phasors in an AC circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits

In a circuit with a DC source, KVL states that $\sum_{i} V_{i}=0$, so I am wondering if i would translate this law into AC circuits, would be the statement that the vectorial sum of phasors equal zero?

Comment: Yes, but the moment you have inductors, KVL is not applicable and you should be using Faraday's Law directly.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent that is not correct. Inductors as a lumped element are perfectly consistent with KVL. It is the lumped element, not the induction, that is the issue

Comment: @Dale That KVL can be hacked to accept inductors does not mean that KVL is applicable. The electric field can no longer be described by an electrostatic potential because things stop being conservative, and the assumptions inside KVL ceases to apply.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent It works on the bench, so whether some arbitrary set of assumptions applies is irrelevant. In physics, the phenomena are fundamental.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent as John Doty says, it is an experimental fact that it works. Additionally, it is on sound theoretical footing. One of the assumptions of circuit theory is that the various circuit elements can be treated as lumped elements. This means in particular that the magnetic fields are contained within some finite region defining the lumped element. From that assumption it can be proven that the power to and from a lumped element depends on the product of the current and potential at a number of "ports", regardless of the magnetic field within the element. That is all KVL claims

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent The definition of "voltage" in KVL and in theory of AC circuits is not integral of total electric field, but integral of its conservative component, thus, difference of the Coulomb-gauge electric potential. Thus KVL is always valid, trivially.

Comment: @JánLalinský Then it will never be able to capture the inductance part. That's the whole point. I cannot help people who want to insist on being wrong, but it is so easy to prove these things one way or the other.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent that is not the point or usual use of KVL. KVL does not provide expression for voltage on inductor, or make any statement on induction. KVL just states sum of potential drops in closed path is zero. Ideal inductors have potential drop $LdI/dt$, and this is often used with success. But this is additional assumption valid for ideal inductors only. Complicated induction scenarios with real inductors or with distributed parameters still obey KVL, but they are more complicated in the sense the potential drops are not expressible as $LdI/dt$.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Your homework is to go to the bench and build a circuit whose operation proves that KVL can never capture the inductance part. Real physics, not mere whiteboard abstraction.

Comment: @JánLalinský If you already agreed that "KVL just states sum of potential drops in closed path is zero." then you should have seen that there is no such thing as it being able to cover inductors, ideal or not. The integral of the electric field over a closed path is NOT zero when you take the inductance into account. It is not a potential drop. It is non-conservative.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent KVL "is not able to cover inductors" is a misleading statement showing your misunderstanding of circuit theory. KVL is routinely used for circuits with inductors. KVL is not supposed to provide and it does not provide the formula for potential drop on inductor $LdI/dt$. Only in *that* sense it does not "cover inductors", just as it does not give formula for potential drop on resistor $RI$, or $Q/C$ on capacitor. KVL is one of the few fundamental rules used to formulate the correct equations for a circuit.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent validity of KVL for circuits with inductors has been covered here and elsewhere several times. See e.g. my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/605983/31895

Comment: @JánLalinský I cannot help the lot of you who are explicitly intending to get it wrong. There is absolutely no need to defend KVL either---Faraday's Law is KVL with correction, so that it would be the correct drop-in replacement whenever KVL is placed. And for the fact that no potential is useful, let this experiment prove it to you: https://youtu.be/eqjl-qRy71w

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent yeah right, generations of physicists and engineers are getting it wrong, but somehow AC circuits work as designed using KVL, that is complete random luck. KVL has nothing to do with Faraday's law, not in its modern form (about sum of potential drops), not in its original form (Kirchhoff's 2nd circuital law about sum of emfs, a generalization of Ohm's law).

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Mr. Lewin's example is not a lumped element circuit, and KVL, while true, is not useful, because potential drops on the circuit elements cannot be determined. His example is correctly analyzed via the original Kirchhoff's 2nd circuital law. He does not understand KVL or Kirchhoff's 2nd circuital law - neither is a special case of Faraday's law.

Comment: @JánLalinský It is very clear that you have not even bothered to learn the objections being given to you, and you do not even attempt to understand the position you are claiming "Sum of EMF" is either "sum of potential drops" or really "line integral of electric field", and it is clear that it is the former case that Kirchhoff was originally talking about.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent If you want to know what Kirchhoff was originally talking about, read his writings on 2nd circuital law. It was not about potential drops. You're in for a ride.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and it's routine to do so when designing linear circuits. However, it's often disguised by using the substitution $i\omega\rightarrow s$ to give the resulting polynomials real coefficients (Fourier versus Laplace transforms). That puts you on well-trodden algebraic paths.

Comment: So, this should necessarily mean that if summed the phasors of all of the components in an ac circuit, it should be at 180°phase difference with the source  right?

Comment: @Jack That is true.